# mkdir(folder_name) with 755 permission in php

Tags: php, filesystems, file-permissions, mkdir

I have my web application hosted in **/var/www** folder. I am creating a folder from one of the PHP scripts of the web application. The default permission of the created folder is `drwx------`, i.e. 700. But I want that folder to have at least 755 permission.

Up to now I tried:  `mkdir($path, 0755)` and `chmod($path, 0755)` PHP functions but without any success.

Does anybody know how to solve my problem please?

Millions of thanks beforehand.

Comment: please set `error_reporting( E_ALL )` to be certain you're not being warned of insufficient permissions. Is the mkdir command failing? You might not have write access to the location you're trying to write to (or the path could be incorrect).

Comment: No, I am creating a folder itself, but as I had said above it has a permission of 700.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor, does the folder already exist when you try to create it?

Comment: No, the folder is being created every time I run the script.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697595/why-cant-my-php-script-chmod-a-file-it-creates/5697914

Comment: Yeah, the umask will solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, Bakhtiyor have you got any solution? If yes please edit with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the umask ?

Have a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

The easiest way it to:

```php
$oldmask = umask(0);
chmod($path, 0755);
umask($oldmask)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have default permission of 700, which means the parent directory (the directory in which you are trying to create the folder) do not have rw permission for group owner or other users. Most often the running demon(httpd) is not the owner of the parent folder and hence cannot modify the directory.

In simple terms, the php script do not have access to modify or add new directory. You need to change the permission of the **parent folder** to at least  **drwxrw-rw-** (or 0755).

Use ssh, cpanel or ftp client to do this. If you do it using php script you will end with the same problem again, as parent of parent will have again 0700. ;)